# Problems to download excel-list Laravel 9

Tags: php, excel, laravel

We have the opportunity to download results as an excel-file like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/frGxQ.jpg  But this doesn't work here in Laravel 9.
This is how it looks in pdf: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEzR6.jpg
I have replaced  the create() to download() but hen I got the error

Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::download(): Argument #2 ($fileName) must be of type string, Closure given

in MaatwebsiteExcelRepository:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Contracts\ExcelInterface;
use Excel;

class MaatwebsiteExcelRepository implements ExcelInterface
{
    /**
     * Creates a file based on given data.
     *
     * @param  string $filename
     * @param  array $rows
     * @param  array $args
     * @return object
     */
    public function create($filename, $rows, $args = [])
    {
        $args['title'] = $this->getTitle($args);
        $args['creator'] = $this->getCreator($args);
        $args['company'] = $this->getCompany($args);
        $args['description'] = $this->getDescription($args);
        $args['keywords'] = $this->getKeywords($args);

        $filenameParts = pathinfo($filename);
        $filename = $filenameParts['filename'];

**COMMENT Next line gives the error**
        return Excel::download($filename, function ($excel) use ($rows, $args) {
            $excel->setTitle($args['title']);
            $excel->setCreator($args['creator']);
            $excel->setCompany($args['company']);
            $excel->setDescription($args['description']);
            $excel->setKeywords($args['keywords']);

            if (count($rows) === 0) {
                $rows[0] = [];
            }

            $excel->sheet('sheet1', function ($sheet) use ($rows) {

                // Make the header row bold.
                $sheet->cells('1:1', function ($cells) {
                    $cells->setFontWeight('bold');
                });

                if (! empty($rows[0])) {

                    // Make sure all columns in the rows are strings.
                    foreach ($rows as $rowIndex => $row) {
                        if (! empty($row) && is_array($row)) {
                            $rows[$rowIndex] = array_map('strval', $row);
                        } else {
                            $rows[$rowIndex] = $row;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $sheet->fromArray($rows);
            });

            // Create an empty second sheet, which is the default for most excel files.
            $excel->sheet('sheet2', function ($sheet) use ($rows) {
            });
        });
    }
```

So this:

```
return Excel::download($filename, function ($excel) use ($rows, $args)
```

must be rearranged some way.

But how?

As before this works in Laravel 5.3
But MaatwebsiteExcelRepository is now version 3.1, before 2 in Laravel 5.3

Comment: Put a dummy string as file name and try again. `Excel::download('dummy-file-name', ...`. If it works make sure you serve the $filename as a string.

Comment: No change. Note that error says Argument #2 ($fileName), not $filename so it must refer to this: ", function ($excel) use ($rows, $args)" as it's the Argument #2. And that I think is a closure, and the following $excel->set... is building up that closure. So maybe the statement must produce a string in the new version of MaatwebsiteExcelRepository